# Is there any problem with security if I store userid ,username and other such kind information in cookie

Tags: security, cookies

Is there any problem with security if I store userid,profileId,username and other such kind  information in cookie.

Comment: What other? And what will you be doing with the username in a cookie?

Comment: This information need very often,and instead of do Sql query every time I can one time get this information from Sql,store it in cookie(when user login) and then get it from cookie.I think it will be more efficient.

Comment: You definitelly need to store these data in the http session which is close to the server and not to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there will be an enormous security problem doing this. If you don't encrypt the cookie anyone could replace the username you've stored with say for example *Administrator* (usually id=1) and send a request to the web server.

Comment: Depends on how he is using the cookies.

Comment: @cherouvim, that's correct but I assume that if he wants to store the userid and profileid in the cookie its to be able to identify the user on the server.

Comment: I think you can encrypt all userdata but the username and save only username and key on your server. This way you can save space on your server and noone can maipulate the userdata. (If someone changes the username the key won't fit.)

Comment: @kasten, all this are some hypothetical scenarios. The OP asked if there's a security problem storing userid,profileid,username inside a cookie without mentioning anything about encryption (if he did he should also mention what algorithm should be used, etc.., remember the famous Padding Oracle Attack) and without further information it seems that there's a big security risk.

Answer (score 0):

> This information need very often,and instead of do Sql query every time I can one time get this information from Sql,store it in cookie(when user login) and then get it from cookie.I think it will be more efficient.

Yes, you can do that BUT ONLY IF IT IS NOT CRITICAL THAT THIS DATA BE CORRECT.

The user can edit his own cookie.

If he wants to change his display name to something else, or get a different background picture, probably no problem.

If he can impersonate other users, big problem.

So, to be on the safe side, better not go down this road.

If you need performance improvements, consider server-side caching solutions instead.